# Vuejs : Force to not reuse same component when navigating?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm using `Vuejs` in my project and it works fine.

But I'm now facing an issue.

I have a component `UserForm` which I use for reading users (route name: `UserFormView`) and to create them (route name: `UserFormCreate`).
When I'm on the form view of a user, I have a button available `Create Another` which is supposed to open the `UserForm`to create a new user.
The thing is, since it is the same component, it seems that it is reused and I have to reset all data manually to obtain a clean form.

I'd like it to destroy the current form and remount a new one instead so that I don't have to do some manual data reset...

How could I achieve it ?

I didn't find a way to do it, even in the documentation (maybe my research was crap) or in other posts.

My App.vue :

```html
<template>
  <v-app>
    <app-header @toggle-sidebar-miniVariant="toggleSidebarMiniVariant()"/>
    <app-sidebar ref="sidebar"/>
    <app-footer/>
    <v-content>
      <router-view/>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

Then my two routes for the UserForm :

```js
{ path: '/user/create', name: 'UserFormCreate', component: UserForm, props: true },
{ path: '/user/:userId', name: 'UserFormView', component: UserForm, props: true },
```

You can see that I use the same component.
So when I'm on my `UserFormView`, I want to get the same component but clean to be able to create a new one.

```html
<v-btn v-if="!editing && user !== undefined" @click="createAnother()">
  <v-icon small class="mr-1">mdi-plus</v-icon>
  Create Another
</v-btn>
```

Currently to get it work, I do it :

```js
createAnother () {
  this.resetDefaultData()
  this.$router.push({ name: 'UserFormCreate', params: { editing: true } })
},

resetDefaultData () {
  Object.assign(this.$data, this.setDefaultData())
},

setDefaultData () {
  return {
    user: undefined,
    groupsUserHasNot: [],
    form: {
      username: '',
      password: '',
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      isActive: true
    },
    showPassword: false,
    selectedGroups: []
  }
},
```

and my initial data () :

```js
data () {
  return this.setDefaultData()
},
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read this. There is an answer and you will learn a lot ;-) https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try with the key-thing first and see if I can manage to do it.

Comment: Does the key thing work from within itself ? I mean the component I have to reset is `this`. Not a child component.

Comment: maybe you need to work on your architecture.

Comment: You can always call `this.$forceUpdate()`

Comment: @A.Lau How would you design it ? Currently I use the same component for the Form View (to read information) and for the Create View. The thing is that I change the `disabled` props with a "edit" button.

Comment: Here is how I would do it, users have UUID's that can be generated client side. When you load your component you give this component a key property. `<component :key="user.uuid" /`> When creating a new user you generate the uuid before loading the component and give this as the key. You can use this uuid to store the user to, your comopnent still has the advantages of the render engine, but can use it in multiple ways.

Comment: @S.Visser But I never call such a component like that. In my main app, it's `<router-view/>` and I open them through buttons and `:to` props.

Comment: @IVOGELOV I tried the `this.$forceUpdate()` thing in a method `createAnother () { this.$forceUpdate() }` that I call with a `@click="createAnother()"` button. But it does nothing. Maybe because the route for reading in the view is `/user/:userId` and for creating is `/user/create` (despite that it is the same component)

Comment: Then you should concider changing your architecture. `<router-view>` loads your view components, your view components contain the functional components (e.g. forms, lists, thumbnail loader, password change ect ect ). Thats kind of the component based architecture in a nutshell.

Comment: @S.Visser I don't see any other way to do so in fact. My main app have custom components that are rendered on each view : `AppHeader` `AppSidebar` `AppFooter` and alongside I have `<v-content> <router-view/> </v-content>` so when I change from `UserForm` to `UserList` (for instance), only the content part of the app changes from my form to my list of user (considering the example I just gave)

Comment: @S.Visser I edited my post to show how I got it to work, but I don't like it because it seems like a workaround.

Comment: I echo @S.Visser's sentiments. UserForm is a generic component and shouldn't be rendered directly in the router view. Use a dummy parent component instead, which consumes `<UserForm>`, then, you can always `v-bind:key` to ensure that UserForm is re-rendered.

Comment: @Terry I see I would have to consider `UserForm` as a generic.. Then I would have separated components `UserFormView` and `UserFormCreate` that both use `UserForm`, which result in `<template> <user-form/> </template>` (something like that) for both of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comments provided by @S.Visser @Terry and @A.Lau I changed the "architecture" of my components.

I ended up with 2 new components `UserFormCreate` and `UserFormRead` (which have each a dedicated route) that both embed a `UserForm`. That last one does not have a route associated but is used in the 2 previous instead.

It keeps the DRY principle since my `UserForm` is written only once.
And I'm able to call it with different props so it suits my need.

Since it was the main concern, I don't have to forceUpdate() or whatever to obtain the result I wanted to achieve too.

Instead when I hit the `Create Another` button it simply calls the URL of `UserFormCreate` and so it render a new `UserForm`.

> UserFormRead :

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid>
    <user-form :userId="userId"/>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import UserForm from './UserForm'
export default {
  name: 'UserFormRead',
  components: {
    UserForm
  },
  props: {
    userId: { type: Number, default: null }
  }
}
</script>
```

> UserFormCreate :

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid>
    <user-form :editing="true"/>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import UserForm from './UserForm'
export default {
  name: 'UserFormCreate',
  components: {
    UserForm
  }
}
</script>
```

> The 2 routes associated :

```
{ path: '/user/create', name: 'UserFormCreate', component: UserFormCreate, props: true },
{ path: '/user/:userId', name: 'UserFormRead', component: UserFormRead, props: true },
```

I won't show the `UserForm` here since it is very long and there is no reason to do so since it wasn't the point.